# Unable to get informations from a Html5 CSS and php form

Tags: php, css, html, forms

I try to build a html5 form and send informations to form.php

```
<h3>Contact Me</h3>
<p></p>
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="6u 12u(xsmall)">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u(xsmall)">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" class="special" value="Send Message" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

At the same place I have form.php

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    echo 'name '.$_POST['name'].' mail '.$_POST['email'];
}
?>
```

When I click on submit `form.php` page is open but blank.

Comment: opening tag `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: Is your web server configured to handle (execute) .php files?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
echo 'name '.$_POST['name'].' mail '.$_POST['email'];
}
?>
```

I think you missed the opening of PHP tag its `<?php` and not `<?` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes sorry, now I can send by mail.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: lespizz'; 
$to = 'jim@fdfrdsfg.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)
?>
```

do you know how to get back on index.html automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: your `mail()` function missing an semicolon. For redirect you can use `header('Location:index.html');` or javascript `window.history.back();` or `window.location.href = 'index.html';`

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP you may redirect to another page with this code :

```
header("Location: index.html");
die();
```

But beware - it will work only if there was no output before!

Or if you have to give some output earlier you may just echo Javascript to redirect :

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
      </script>';
```